# Как определить событие change() Bootsrap Chosen

Tags: jquery, javascript, bootstrap

В проекте используется данный плагин - [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) - с атрибутом `Multiselect`
При выборе нового элемента или удалении элемента (событие `change()`),
необходимо подсчитать количество выбранных элементов из общего количества. Cобытие change()
не подходит, так как сначала производится подсчет элементов, а только потом происходит удаление\добавление элементов. Как быть?

Comment: Не работал с этой библиотекой и не совсем понимаю, почему change() работает не так, как вам нужно. Возможно, вам поможет ведение счетчика, который бы вы увеличивали\уменьшали, когда элемент добавляют\удаляют. Таким образом счетчик и будет необходимым результатом

Comment: сделайте nextTick в хэндлере change -  обычно это setTimeout(realhandler,0); 

вот это не работает ? `$("#form_field").chosen().change( … );` по идее оно должно оборачивать как надо.

Comment: Да, вот именно это и не работает  $("#form_field").chosen().change( … ); Единственный момент, у меня select не вложен в тег form,
setTimeout это не вариант, тк у разных пользователей разное время отклика, а делать задержку секунд в 5 тем более не вариант

Comment: при чем тут задержка у пользователей ?

Comment: сделайте nextTick в хэндлере change - обычно это setTimeout(realhandler,0);

А можно в jsfiidle если не затруднит, не совсем понял ваши мысли

Comment: @ruslik нарисуйте в jsfiddle скелет, чтобы не получалось, я покажу как.